# Can I stay overnight [15-hour layover] in Haneda airport without a Japan visa?

Tags: transit-visas, layovers, filipino-citizens, hnd

I’m a Filipino citizen. My flight goes from Vancouver to Manila via Tokyo Haneda. I will arrive in Japan at 6pm then depart at 9am the next day. I'm not planning to go out of the airport during my layover, so I don't see a need to have a transit visa. However, I called the Consulate-General of Japan here in Canada, and they asked me to get a transit visa.

Then I called the Ministry of Foreign Affairs in Japan and asked them the same question.. at first, they told me I don’t need a visa as long as I stay inside the airport, but when I told them that the Consulate-General of Japan in Canada asked me to get a visa, they also asked me to get one.

I'm so confused. I would like to know your knowledge or experience regarding this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I stay overnight \[15-hour layover\] in Haneda airport without a Japan visa?\]](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/129750/can-i-stay-overnight-15-hour-layover-in-haneda-airport-without-a-japan-visa)

Answer (score 4):

Per TIMATIC, the database used by airlines:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa): Passengers transiting through **Tokyo (HND)** or Osaka (KIX)
>     with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third
>     country within 72 hours. They must stay in the international
>     transit area of the airport and have documents required for
>     the next destination.

and

> Holders of onward tickets transiting to a third country can obtain a Shore Pass on arrival for a max. stay of 72 hours only if there are no connecting flights on the same calendar day

As such, you don't need a visa, even if leaving the airport. If you want to leave the airport present your passport and connecting boarding pass at border control, and ask for a Shore pass.

Comment: It's also worth noting that this is the case because Haneda operates 24/7, while Narita does not.

Comment: Hi, I don’t know how the domestic terminal and international terminals work. As for me, I’ll be arriving at terminal 1 (domestic terminal) at 6pm, then will leave 9am the next day (as stated in my question above). But they said the domestic terminal will be closed at night. Am I allowed to stay inside the terminal?

Comment: Also, how can I obtain a shore pass? I’m sorry this is my first time to encounter these things

Comment: And, can I get a shore pass if I arrive and depart  from the domestic terminal?

Comment: I’m sorry, I don’t actually know if it’s Terminal 1 or International terminal. I was so confused because it was written as “Terminal I” in my ticket. I’m currently put on hold by an ANA (All Nippon Airways) agent because she is also figuring out if it’s Terminal 1 or International Terminal

Comment: @Eishiele Doesn't matter; you get the Shore pass at passport control. It's nothing special, just an entry stamp for 72 hours

Comment: The Japanese airport staff are very friendly at all airports in Japan (I've flown via Narita, Haneda, and KIX, and all the staff were very nice).  If you don't know where to go, just ask when you get there.  You may need to start by asking for an English-speaking staff member (or Filipino-speaking, which they may have!) to ask for directions for you in Japanese.